# Rock Paper Scissor with a CPU (console)

Tags: python, python-3.x, rock-paper-scissors

I tried my hands on Rock-Paper-Scissors. But the twist is that the game has a brain that aims to learns your behaviour.

The brain is a simple counter that updates the player's current choice based on players previous choices. The `level` determines the number of previous choices cpu will remember. In any event the player tracks its own inputs and makes calculated choices to defeat the CPU, I have added a [*timed input*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15533404/8363478) function i.e. if you don't provide input within 5 secs, you lose.

The game works perfectly, however I am unhappy with the `main` function. There are too many try-except blocks. My questions are

- What are possible improvements ?
- How do I improve the `print_cpu_data` function in the way it shows the information ?
- If I wish to make a GUI for the game (e.g tkinter, Pygame, etc), what part of the code should be made into functions and how to do so efficiently ?

As I am not a beginner (somewhat less than intermediate) , I appreciate some advanced ideas and concepts.

```py
"""
Rock-Paper-Scissor with CPU
"""
from itertools import product
import select
import sys

SCORE_TABLE = [[1, 0, 2],
               [2, 1, 0],
               [0, 2, 1]]
SCORE_STR = ['LOSE', 'DRAW', 'WIN']
ROCK = 0
PAPER = 1
SCISSOR = 2
CHOICE_STR = ['ROCK', 'PAPER', 'SCISSOR']
WIN_MOVE = [PAPER, SCISSOR, ROCK]


class GameCpu:
    """Class to create game CPU"""
    def __init__(self, level=1):
        self.level = level
        self.probs = {}
        for t in product([ROCK, PAPER, SCISSOR], repeat=level):
            self.probs[t] = [0, 0, 0]
        self.prev = [0]*level

    def get_cpu_choice(self):
        """Return CPU choice"""
        tmp = self.probs[tuple(self.prev)]
        pred = tmp.index(max(tmp))
        return WIN_MOVE[pred]

    def train_cpu(self, choice_player):
        """Train CPU with current player choice"""
        self.probs[tuple(self.prev)][choice_player] += 1
        self.prev.pop(0)
        self.prev.append(choice_player)

    def print_cpu_data(self):
        """Print CPU data"""
        print('\nPattern', '\t'*self.level, 'Choice count\n')
        for key, val in self.probs.items():
            print(*[f'{CHOICE_STR[k]}' for k in key], sep=', ', end='\t\t')
            print(*[f'{CHOICE_STR[i]}:{v}' for i, v in enumerate(val)])


def input_with_timeout(prompt, timeout):
    """Timed input"""
    sys.stdout.write(prompt)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    ready, _, _ = select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], timeout)
    if ready:
        return sys.stdin.readline().rstrip('\n')
    raise Exception

def main():
    """main function"""
    while True:
        try:
            level = int(input('Enter CPU level (Level 1,2,3): '))
            assert 1 <= level <= 3
            break
        except:
            print('Invalid.')

    print('\nPress Q to quit game\
        \nRemember you have got only 5secs to give input.\
        \nThe choices are ROCK:1  PAPER:2  SCISSOR:3\n')

    cpu = GameCpu(level)
    scores = [0, 0, 0]
    timeout = 5
    while True:
        choice_player = None
        try:
            choice_player = input_with_timeout('Enter choice: ', timeout)
        except:
            print('Times up')

        if not choice_player:
            break
        if choice_player.lower() == 'q':
            break
        try:
            choice_player = int(choice_player)-1
            assert 0 <= choice_player <= 2
        except:
            print('Invalid. ', end='\n')
            continue

        choice_cpu = cpu.get_cpu_choice()
        s = SCORE_TABLE[choice_player][choice_cpu]
        scores[s] += 1
        print(f'{SCORE_STR[s]}')

        cpu.train_cpu(choice_player)

    total = max(1, sum(scores))
    percent = [100*s/total for s in scores]

    print('\nSTATS: \n')
    print(f'Total games played: {total}')
    print(*[f'{SCORE_STR[i]}:{p:.2f}% ' for i, p in enumerate(percent)])
    cpu.print_cpu_data()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: When I executed your code it didn't allow me to intoduce any input, only the level of the CPU

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 3):

#### How do I improve the print_cpu_data function in the way it shows the information ?

Well, nowadays the most common architectural pattern (design scheme) for many projects is the MVC its principle is to separate the classes and code constructs in your project into 3 packages (model-view-controller)

- In the model goes *all the code which constitutes your application logic* for example your class `GameCpu`
- In the view goes *the code which displays the information that the user is supposed to see* in exmaple a class which uses `tkinter, Pygame` etc.
- In the controller goes the code which allows communication between model and view.

You need to be aware that Desktop apps and Web apps have a different approach for the MVC due its nature.

#### If I wish to make a GUI for the game (e.g tkinter, Pygame, etc), what part of the code should be made into functions and how to do so efficiently ?

As I said, you could use an MVC pattern which is basically 3 packages named model, view, controller and import classes accordingly.

I believe your question is more likely to be answered with **modularization** and **refactoring**

Modularization is to split independent code blocs into functions, and refactoring is to simplify the code you have written.

Well, I hope it helped you, maybe you need a couple of youtube videos to understand how MVC works. I know, it seems more work, but when you are debugging medium to semi-large *personal projects* it is worthy, in great scale projects its indispensable. (not just MVC, to use an architectural pattern with an enterprise architecture [the names makes it sound complex but actually it isn't]).

Note: You may ask why did i not answered your first question, well, the code does not work when I execute it, so I can't make suggestions in the air, plus if I recommend a new form to solve this problem, many mods request answers to be bassed on the poster's code.